# Angular 7 Keypair expression order

Tags: angular, key-value

I'm trying to build a table out with Angular 7 that has a table as a parent component with child components of each row  with the exception of the first row. I am passing in a keyvalue pipe value into each row and before the child components are displayed, I also loop through the keyvalue pair in the parent component first (see image). I'm using `ngFor` to loop through the keyvalue pair but I'm fighting the order it's displaying in the child components. I know by default, keyvalue is returned in alphabetical order based on the key. I was able to set use `null` on the parent component `ngFor` for it's expression and it works fine, but I get an error in the child components when I try to use null for the expression. Here's what I got:

**table.component.ts**

This is in the export class.

```
intervals: {[key: string]: string} = {
    'past-hour': 'Past Hour',
    'today': 'Today',
    'yesterday': 'Yesterday'
  };

// This is the one that I'm having trouble with.
responseStatus: {[key: string]: string} = {
    'success': 'Success',
    'error': 'Error %',
    'throttle': 'Throttle %'
};
```

**table.component.html**

```
<table class="compare-table text-right">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <!-- The null works here -->
      <td *ngFor="let status of responseStatus | keyvalue: null">
        {{ status.value }}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr 
      table-row 
      *ngFor="let interval of intervals | keyvalue: null" 
      [interval]="interval" 
      [responseStatuses]="responseStatus">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**table-row.component.ts**

```
export class TableRowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() interval; 
  @Input() responseStatuses: {[key: string]: string};

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**table-row.component.html**
This errors on the front end (compiles fine). If I remove the null, it displays but in alphabetical order by key. So instead of success, error, and throttle like it does on the first row, it displays error, success, throttle.

```
<td>
  {{ interval.value}}
</td>
<td *ngFor="let response of responseStatuses | keyvalue: null">
  {{ response.value }}
</td>
```

How it gets displayed without the null in the child:
[image: How the table gets rendered]

I appreciate any feedback anyone has. I'm extremely new to this and wanted to learn what the heck I was doing wrong. :) Thanks!

**UPDATE**
As it turns out the console didn't like the null on the parent component either but it worked... All I want to do is display the keyvalue pair in the order it's set--not in alphabetical order. Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzsgwz).

Comment: Any way to build a simple stackblitz that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Yes! https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzsgwz . This is a super basic example. As it turns out, the parent component also errors with the null but works. Basically I just want keyvalue pair to show in the order it's set and not in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation here: https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

> The output array will be ordered by keys. By default the comparator
>   will be by Unicode point value. You can optionally pass a compareFn if
>   your keys are complex types.

So the ordering is *by design*. As it states, you could provide a compare function, but I don't see how that would help. There would be no "as written" ordering (that I know of).

The `keyvalue` pipe is relatively new ... so one option here would be to do it how we did it before the `keyvalue` pipe, and that is to handle it in code.

In the component:

```
  get keys() : Array<string> {
    console.log(this.responseStatus);
    return Object.keys(this.responseStatus);
  }
```

This code returns just the set of keys in the order they are defined.

In the html:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
  {{ responseStatus[key] }}
</div>
```

This code loops through those keys and accesses the element from the key and value pair.

Updated stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xucsn6

Comment: That was it! Thank you @DeborahK! I just tought there would have been an easier way to do it.